# How to use QLineEdit mask with Russian letters?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qtcore, qlineedit

I need that case of `QLineEdit` was always lower. I will use it with russian letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply apply the "toLower" principle, albeit not for `QString` as that is always handled with "C" locale, but `QLocale` as per Qt documentation:

> QString QLocale::toLower(const QString & str) const
>
> Returns a lowercase copy of str. This function was introduced in QtCore 4.8.

You could use `QValidator` for the `QLineEdit` as well if you wish (based on your "initial request"):

> void QValidator::setLocale(const QLocale & locale)
>
> Sets the locale that will be used for the validator. Unless setLocale has been called, the validator will use the default locale set with QLocale::setDefault(). If a default locale has not been set, it is the operating system's locale.

and:

> State QValidator::validate(QString & input, int & pos) const [pure virtual]
>
> This virtual function returns Invalid if input is invalid according to this validator's rules, Intermediate if it is likely that a little more editing will make the input acceptable (e.g. the user types "4" into a widget which accepts integers between 10 and 99), and Acceptable if the input is valid.
>   The function can change both input and pos (the cursor position) if required.

Once you have your own validator implementation, you can use the following setter of `QLineEdit` to actually use your validation:

> void QLineEdit::setValidator(const QValidator * v)
>
> Sets this line edit to only accept input that the validator, v, will accept. This allows you to place any arbitrary constraints on the text which may be entered.
>   If v == 0, setValidator() removes the current input validator. The initial setting is to have no input validator (i.e. any input is accepted up to maxLength()).

Comment: Thank you! I just thougth, that toLower works only with latin.